# How to trigger a migration for new entity on Flutter's Floor?

Tags: flutter, flutter-floor

I have already 2 entities (ex: User, Song) for which I have the entity classes, DAO classes, database working and tables generated inside the device (with data already present).

I want to add the third one (Resource).

How to I trigger this new table to be created upon deploy? All that I could find in the documentation is how to alter a column for an existing table.